# Determine if program was called from a terminal or by running an associated file

Tags: python, windows, nuitka

## Background

I am attempting to create an interpreter for a toy programming language. I built the interpreter with ANTLR4 + Python. Then, I compiled the interpreter using Nuitka and bundled it using Inno Setup. After installing with Inno Setup, the executable can be invoked in two ways:

1. Invoking the name from the terminal. (Running `mylang myfile.code`)
2. Double-click an associated file. (Clicking `myfile.code` in the explorer)

## Issue

When I run the executable by clicking the associated file, a terminal is spawned, but then it immediately disappears when the `myfile.code` program finishes, giving me no time to read the output. I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577467/how-to-pause-a-script-when-it-ends-on-windows) which lead me to `os.system("pause")`. However, when this makes my program pause when it is invoked from the terminal normally, which is unnecessary and unwanted.

## Question

Is there a way to detect which way the program was invoked so I can pause only when it was run from clicking an associated file?

Comment: Maybe add a command line switch to you program which will instruct it to wait before terminating.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a wrong question. For example, what if you run `mylang myfile.code` from <kbd>Win+R</kbd> window? You won't see the output either. On the other hand, what if your code is started from console just by typing `myfile.code`? Then you will be pausing for no reason.

---

What you actually want to check is if your code inherited console from another process (like `cmd`) – meaning that if your code closes, the console window stays open. Or if new console was created implicitly for your code and it will go away with your process.

See [How to check if the program is run from a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9009333/850848)